# Scrolling Navigation Bar

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation, horizontal-scrolling, blackberry-webworks

I am new to mobile web frameworks development and would like to get advice about implementing a navigation bar for my BlackBerry application. I need a fixed nav bar at the top of the screen, however a scrolling one. I looked at jQuery Mobile, but it allows up to 5 items. If more, another row is added below. I need something like this:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Paged-navbar-at-the-top-of-the-page/td-p/1671709

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [More than 5 items per line in jQuery Mobile navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161377/more-than-5-items-per-line-in-jquery-mobile-navbar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More than 5 items per line in jQuery Mobile navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161377/more-than-5-items-per-line-in-jquery-mobile-navbar)